# Disable StrictHostKeyChecking in ssh

Tags: macos, ssh

I am trying to connect to a Linux host using `ssh` and get the following error

```
RSA host key for 10.1.1.20 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
```

I would like to override this, but can't seem to find any combination of options to do this.

I probably set StrictHostKeyChecking years ago, but don't remember how.

I consulted `man ssh` which informs me the system-wide configuration file is `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and default for the per-user configuration file is `~/.ssh/config` neither exists.

EDIT
To clarify my question, the option is clearly set. I am trying to discover

1. Where the options are stored (I don't have the files mentioned in the
   man page, which appears to be wrong).
2. How to change the options.

I am not looking at how to work around the issue I am having (I know I can edit the known_hosts file, but this is tedious every time I try a new server).

Comment: It's `/etc/ssh_config` on mine.

Comment: @sborsky I have this too (which is different from the man) but all options are commented out.

Comment: This means default, which according to the man page is `ask`. When a host key changed, ssh client won't connect unless `StrictHostKeyChecking` is set to `no`. If the host key doesn't change very often, I'd suggest to remove this one host key from your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` instead of changing the config.

Comment: First you must figure out **why** it was changed. If you didn't change it, then it may be a MitM attack, and then you of course should not allow this host key!

Comment: side note - after removing all records for a given host from `.ssh/known_hosts` I continued to get the warning until I discovered the offending row in another file called `.ssh/known_hosts2`.  apparently OS X uses both

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To disable strict host checking on OS X for the current user, create or edit ~/.ssh/config and add the following lines:

```
Host [IP Address] 
   StrictHostKeyChecking no
   UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

A typical example for the hosts in your local network could be:

```
Host 10.1.1.*
   StrictHostKeyChecking no
   UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

Depending on your usage of ssh I don't recommend to disable strict host key checking for **all** hosts.

If you just want to remove the entry for 10.1.1.20 open ~/.ssh/known_hosts with an editor of your choice and remove the respective line "10.1.1.20 ssh-rsa *public-key$*"

Comment: Also seems to work without the /dev/null line.

Comment: This did *not* work without the /dev/null line for me: `Password authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks`

Answer (score 10):

You can simply try it as it is without confitguration, just on commandline:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hostname
```

But I don't think it does all you need. If you want to ignore all hostkey checking, you need to set up you `known_hosts` file to `/dev/null` so there will never be anything stored:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null hostname
```

or in `/etc/ssh_config`:

```
StrictHostKeyChecking no
UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

Comment: The 1st still didn't allow me to connect, but `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null hostname` did. I still can't find WHERE StrictHostKeyChecking is set!

Comment: It defaults to "yes" so it doesn't have to be set anywhere to apply.

Comment: The documentation states it defaults to yes

Comment: choosing as a solution would help if it helped to solve your problem ;)